# Remote Data Access: the user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have read all the related posts here and many other discussions on other forums, but still cannot solve my problem.

I am porting a SQL Server CE application from a WindowsCE device to Win 7. The code of interests is to remotely download a table from SQL Server database using `SqlCeRemoteDataAccess.Pull`.

The original code on WinCE device is as follows:

```
SqlCeRemoteDataAccess.Pull(Tablename, sql, _remoteConnectionString, RdaTrackoption.TrackingOffWithIndexes, "ErrorTable")
```

When running on Win7 from Visual Studio 2012, it complains:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I double checked both my local and remote databases. They are not corrupted. Then I searched the Internet and this forum, and tried the suggested solution: changing the connection string from:

```
Provider=PROVIDER;Data Source=Src;User ID=SUser;Password=1234;Initial Catalog=ABCD_EF;
```

To:

```
Provider=PROVIDER;Data Source=Src;User ID=SUser;Password=1234;Initial Catalog=ABCD_EF;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Now I got:

> Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

I also added `Trusted_Connection=Yes` or `Trusted_Connection=True` to the above connection string and saw the identical error. Any suggestions ? Thank you.

NOTE: The server is already set to mixed mode: both Windows and SQL Server authentication.

NEW updating: I am using C# for programming both for the device and on Win7. The remote data server agent is in sqlcesa30.dll (Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition Server Agent 3.0). The followings are connection strings used and error messages I got:

(1) Original one that Works on WinCE devices, but on Win 7 I got:

```
Provider=PROVIDER;Data Source=Src;User ID=SUser;Password=1234;Initial Catalog=ABCD_EF;

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

(2) On Win 7 I got:

```
Provider=PROVIDER;Data Source=Src;Initial Catalog=ABCD_EF;Integrated Security=SSPI;

Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.
```

(3) On Win 7 I got:

```
Provider=PROVIDER;Data Source=Src;User ID=SUser;Password=1234;Initial Catalog=ABCD_EF;Integrated Security=SSPI;

Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.
```

Comment: Whatever windows user you are connecting with is not set up as a login. Can you add a tag for the version of SQL Server that you are connecting to? Also a tag for whatever language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have **both** the `Integrated Security=SSPI;` **and** `User ID=SUser;Password=1234` in a connection string at once. **Pick one**:

- either use the integrated security (recommended) to use your current credentials - but then you **must remove** the `UserID=...;Password=....` parts from the connection string
- or then you use a specific user and password - and in this case, adding integrated security or trusted connection is moot since the `UserID=...;Password=...` settings will be used

So in your case, if you have properly set up integrated security, just use:

```
Data Source=Src;Initial Catalog=ABCD_EF;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

as your connection string.